# Rotate MUI svg icon with transition effect

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to enable my svg icon to rotate onClick and here is my code:

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false);

const handleExpand =() => {
    setExpanded(!expanded)
}

<Box>
<IconButton onClick={handleExpand}>
    <ExpandMoreIcon sx={{ transform: accordionExpanded ? "transform(180deg)" : "transform(0deg)"}} />
</IconButton>
<Box>
<Collapse in={expanded}>Hello</Collapse>
```

Currently this does not work, and my icon still remains un-rotated. I'd like to also enable a transition effect, such as `transition: all 100ms ease 10s`. I'm not very familiar with CSS and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have a lot at [MDN’s `transform` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). You will want to use `rotate`

Comment: Thank you, I realised I typed ```transform(0deg)``` and ```transform(180deg)``` wrongly. It should be ```rotate```